# How to get the Resource Group of a resource in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-group

I have resources in a Resource Group in Azure and it wont let me move the resource because it is in a Resource Group that is not the hosting Resource Group even though it has been moved .

I have tried to run the command in Powershell az resource list but cant seem to see the hosting Resource Group of the resource.

Is there a command I can run in Powershell that will give the current Resource Group of the resource and the hosting Resource Group of the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a Powershell command that will give the current Resource Group of the resource?

Yes its the [Get-AzureRmResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-9.2.0) command:

```
$resourceId = "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}"

$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId
$resourceGroupName = $resource.ResourceGroupName
```

Fortunately there's an alternative to avoid specifying the "ResourceGroupName" which you're trying to find and that's specifying the ResourceType..

```
$resourceGroupName = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName {resourceName} -ResourceType {resourceType} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName
```

Also note the `-ExpandProperties` parameter in the documentation to include the resource properties.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared information, I have understood that you want to know the

- hosted resource group(in which resource group got created before move operation).
- current resource group (currently where the resource resides in).

We don't have any direct cmdlets to pull this information.

You can make use of activity logs to see the resource move operation and pull the information of resources which were moved & respective target resource group names accordingly using the below cmdlet

```
Get-AzActivityLog -StartTime (get-date).AddDays(-90) -EndTime (get-date)| Where-Object {$_.Authorization.Action -like "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/moveresources/action" -and $_.OperationName -like "Move Resource Group Resources" -and  $_.EventName -like "Begin request" } | Select -ExpandProperty Properties
```

**Sample screenshot for your reference:**

[image]

**Note**: Using `Get-AzActivityLog` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/powershell/module/az.monitor/get-azactivitylog?view=azps-9.2.0) you can pull logs for only last 90days.

Comment: I can do that no problem , but it doesnt actually give the hosting RG . I will need to wait until an error is displayed and move resources accordingly; its strange they dont have a cmdlet that gives hosting RG.